# Can we use break statement within forEach loop in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, treemap

I am trying to iterate over a TreeMap in java using the `forEach` loop in Java 8. I want break out of the loop when `max == v` but i am getting an error "**break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch**".  Here's a section of the code.

```
tm.forEach(
            (k,v)->{
                if(max == v)
                {
                    System.out.print(k + " "+ v);
                    break;
                }
            }
            );
```

So my question is Can we use break statement inside `forEach` loop and if yes then what is the mistake i am doing?
I am using eclipse Neon with Java8.

Comment: You cannot use break. If you need `break` functionality, you need to use an actual `for` loop. There's probably a dupe for this.

Comment: The closest you can come is in Java 9, with takeWhile. `foo.entrySet().stream().takeWhile(e -> max != e.getValue()).forEach(e -> System.out.print(e.getKey() + " "+ e.getValue()));`

Comment: @Michael the OP’s code only prints the first match, so `filter(…) .findFirst() .ifPresent(…)` would do. No need for `takeWhile`.